# How do I debug a bison program on a unix system?

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, bison, flex-lexer

I have made a compiler for a subset of C called the BabyC using the Bison and flex. My program consists of the following files:

ast.c,ast.h, linkedList.c, linkedList.h, BabyC.y, BabyC.l, main.c, symbolTable.c, symbolTable.h, codeGenerator.c, codeGenerator.h

and finally, a make file which is as follows:

```
CC = gcc
WARNFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra
DEBUGFLAGS = -g -O0

all: bcc

OBJS := BabyC.tab.o BabyC.yy.o ast.o symbolTable.o codeGenerator.o linkedList.o main.o

bcc: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(WARNFLAGS) $(DEBUGFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(WARNFLAGS) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -c $<

%.yy.c: %.l
    flex -o $@ $<

%.tab.c: %.y
    bison -o $@ -d $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.tab.* *.yy.* bcc bcc.out
```

My test case, which is a simple program in the BabyC language is of the extension ".bc"

With all of the files in a single directory, on my system, I type "make" which gives me the required ".o" files and also a bcc file based on the above makefile. My make command looks something like this:

```
akaidecember@DESKTOP-JCU5EAP://mnt/c/Users/akaid/Google Drive/src$ make
bison -o BabyC.tab.c -d BabyC.y
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -O0 -c BabyC.tab.c
In file included from BabyC.y:2:0:
ast.h:80:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
 };
 ^
flex -o BabyC.yy.c BabyC.l
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -O0 -c BabyC.yy.c
In file included from BabyC.l:2:0:
ast.h:80:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
 };
 ^
BabyC.yy.c: In function ‘yy_get_next_buffer’:
BabyC.yy.c:1239:44: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
  if ((int) ((yy_n_chars) + number_to_move) > YY_CURRENT_BUFFER_LVALUE->yy_buf_size) {
                                            ^
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -O0 -c ast.c
In file included from ast.c:3:0:
ast.h:80:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
 };
 ^
ast.c: In function ‘free_ast’:
ast.c:14:3: warning: enumeration value ‘AST_IDENT’ not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
   switch (node->type) {
   ^
ast.c:14:3: warning: enumeration value ‘AST_NUM’ not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -O0 -c symbolTable.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -O0 -c codeGenerator.c
In file included from codeGenerator.h:5:0,
                 from codeGenerator.c:3:
ast.h:80:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
 };
 ^
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -O0 -c linkedList.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -O0 -c main.c
In file included from main.c:5:0:
ast.h:80:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
 };
 ^
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -O0 BabyC.tab.o BabyC.yy.o ast.o symbolTable.o codeGenerator.o linkedList.o main.o -o bcc
rm BabyC.tab.c BabyC.yy.c
akaidecember@DESKTOP-JCU5EAP://mnt/c/Users/akaid/Google Drive/src$
```

Now, a "bcc" file is created. I run the file with the command and the test case file as :

```
./bcc test1.bc
```

and this is my output:

```
akaidecember@DESKTOP-JCU5EAP://mnt/c/Users/akaid/Google Drive/src$ ./bcc test1.bc
Processing declaration of a
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Now, it is really hard for me to trace the segmentation fault manually. So I tried debugging the program using gdb, but I can't get it to work with my program. I tried running the program with gdb running and it tells me that it is an undefined command. I guess it will not run as a normal c ".o" file.

Could anyone help me with how to debug this program? I would like to debug this program and trace the segmentation fault.

Comment: How did you run your program under gdb?  What didn't work?

Comment: Your question gives me the impression that you think the `.o` files are more significant than they actually are.  Note well that it is the executable, `bcc`, not any of the `.o` files, that you need to debug.

Comment: Add `-DYYDEBUG` to `DEBUGFLAGS` before (re)compiling, and set `yydebug = 1;` to `main()` before you call `yyparse()`.  This will give you a lot of information as the parser parses — written to `stderr`, IIRC (and to `stdout` if I don't).

Comment: You run your program under gdb by typing `gdb ./bcc` at the shell prompt, and then typing `run test1.bc` at the (gdb) prompt.  Or you can use `gdb --args ./bcc test1.bc` and then just `run` at the (gdb) prompt.